# Print preview dialog box print button not working

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have a small issue in printing. When I try to print a document from the print preview dialog box. it's not printing anything. If I hide the preview dialog and invoke `pdoc.Print();` it works perfect. Is there any special event for preview dialog button... ?

```
        public void print()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        int w=Convert.ToInt32(Length/2.54)*100;
        int h = Convert.ToInt32(Width / 2.54) * 100;           
       // pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", w, h);
        pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
        pd.Document = pdoc;            
        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
        DialogResult result = pd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            ppd.Document = pdoc;
            ppd.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1.0;
            ((Form)ppd).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            if (cid.Length > 1)// 
            {
                ppd.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 0.75;
                ppd.PrintPreviewControl.Columns = 2;
                ppd.PrintPreviewControl.Rows = 3;
            }

            DialogResult ppdResult = ppd.ShowDialog();

            //Newly Added Code
            if (ppdResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("hai");//this code not executing
                 pdoc.Print();//this code not executing
            }
        }
    }
```

**Updated Code**

```
   void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PrintCount>pc)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            if(CPayAgainstX>0 && CPayAgainstY>0)
                 positionsettings(g, "payagainst", CPayAgainstX, CPayAgainstY, CPayAgainstW, CPayAgainstF);
            if (ChqDateX > 0 && ChqDateY > 0)
                 positionsettings(g, "date", ChqDateX, ChqDateY, ChqDateW, ChqDateF);
            if (ChqAmtWrdsX > 0 && ChqAmtWrdsY > 0)
                 positionsettings(g, "amountword", ChqAmtWrdsX, ChqAmtWrdsY, ChqAmtWrdsW, ChqAmtWrdsF);
            if (ChqAmtDgtX > 0 && ChqAmtDgtY > 0)
                positionsettings(g, "amount", ChqAmtDgtX, ChqAmtDgtY, ChqAmtDgtW, ChqAmtDgtF);


            if(AccountPayeeX>0 && AccountPayeeY>0)
                positionsettings(g, "AccountPayee", AccountPayeeX, AccountPayeeY, AccountPayeeW, AccountPayeeF);

            if (TextField1X > 0 && TextField1Y > 0)
                positionsettings(g, "TextField1", TextField1X, TextField1Y, TextField1W, TextField1F);
            if (TextField2X > 0 && TextField2Y > 0)
                positionsettings(g, "TextField2", TextField2X, TextField2Y, TextField2W, TextField2F);
            if (TextField3X > 0 && TextField3Y > 0)
                positionsettings(g, "TextField3", TextField3X, TextField3Y, TextField3W, TextField3F);

            appendxml_transaction(cid[pc], bankname, templatename, dt[pc], payagainst, amt[pc]);
            pc += 1;
            if (PrintCount > pc)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;                   
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you coded `pdoc_PrintPage` ?

Comment: @TaW yes i have coded. I am getting the print if i directly call `pdoc.Print()` method. the problem when i use preview dialog box button

Answer (score 0):

i've struggle with this issue as well. Found my solution by double checking the
loop while printing multiple page.

// ------------------------------ logic below-----------

Say if i have 3 page to print, i will declare my page number and do increment when go to the next page

int pageNumber = 1

1. drawPage(1)
2. pageNumber increase by 1
3. drawPage(2)
4. pageNumber increase by 1
5. drawPage(3)
6. pageNumber increase by 1

// ------------------------------ logic End -----------

if you notice my, my current pageNumber is 4 and when i try to print the document, the program will start to print darwPage(4)

So what i do to solve this it is to declare my pageNumber and every other parameters to the initial state when i finished drawing all the page in printPreview

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/733680/Printing-and-Previewing-multiple-pages-in-Csharp-2

try to print the same thing like what is done in the webpage provided above.
make sure you are able to print this 3 simple page and then you can add more item(string or line as you wish) in the draw function. Then you are suppose to be able to print all you pages out

Answer (score -1):

Usually a Winforms dialog is used like this:

- first create the dialog,
- then show it, collecting the result
- finally act according to the result

But the `PrintPreviewDialog` doesn't work like that, even though many folks think other wise. (I have a usually reliable book that got it wrong as well..)

Here the printing is started by pressing the 'Print' button/icon and any way to close the dialog returns `cancel`.

The purpose it obvious, when you think of it: The `PrintPreviewDialog` offers the user the choice which page or which pages to print, so it makes sense to keep it open until the user is done with all and closes it.

So why does your code not work?

When you press the 'Print' button the system calls the PrintDocument's `PrintPage` event for each page. If nothing happens you have either not coded that event or got something wrong there. If you did code it, please add its code to your question. I know you must have created it since you have assigned it :

```
pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
```

You may also want to set a breakpoint to it! I'm a little amazed though, since according to the docs the pDoc.Print command also just call PagePrint..so I wonder where any difference in behavious might come from..

Comment: The code inside the if block not executing. I put a message box and debug to verify. When i click on the print button its asking to save the document(i am using microsoft printer) and its save a blank document with one page. actually my document contains 5 page.

Comment: Which if block? your old one? How can pdoc.Print(); sometimes work fine, as you wrote and then, when it comes after the check not?? There must something else wrong!

Comment: I have updated the question with the code you give. please look.

Comment: Forget all about my provious answer and comments. I was wrong about the PrintPreviewDialog, which works quite differently from other Dialogs. Still not sure about your problem, though!

Comment: you describe the theory and i understood it. but didn't mention any solution to my problem.

Comment: Indeed. What I __did__ though is ask you to show us the code of the `pdoc_PrintPage` event and also to test to see if the debugger hits this event!

Comment: i have pasted the code. Yes i tested .debugger hits this event at the point   `ppd.Document = pdoc;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64580/discussion-between-taw-and-jinesh-sam).